# How to expand all folders in the folder pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2013 and sometimes while browsing I'll click on the Inbox entry in the reading pane. Next to that inbox, because I have sub-folders it also has an arrow to the left of it that allows me to collapse subfolders:

[image: Arrow next to inbox]

If I accidently click on it, all of my subfolders get automatically collapsed. If I then click on it again to expand it, it only expands the Inbox and none of the subfolders, they remain collapsed. I then have to click on each subfolder, and any subfolders it has to expand them out again:

[image: All collapsed]

[image: No longer all expanded]

This can get rather infuriating when you have many sub folders and you have to click on each one to expand. Is there any way to do this without having to click each item? The only article I can find on it is [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_2013_release/outlook-2013-any-way-to-expand-all-folders/0aee8c24-b6e7-4896-9946-8fb7d2ba63db). It suggests I press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> which doesn't open the subfolders up, but instead changes the view:

[image: Different view]

Here's what it normally looks like all expanded:

[image: All expanded]

Am I missing a really obvious button that does this? I can't see anything in the context menu or in the menu bar at the top.

Outlook 2016 also lacks this feature.